# Disable shortcut 'ctrl+L' which clears the terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

In Gnome Terminal (Version 3.44.1 for GNOME 42), the shortcut `ctrl+L` clears the terminal (similar to the `clear` command). There does not appear to be an entry for this in the shortcut preferences. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tell us what your shell is.

---

#### Bash

Bash uses [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). In your Bash `bind -p | grep C-l` probably prints:

```
"\C-l": clear-screen
```

(possibly among other lines). To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, you need to remove this binding. In Bash the command is:

```
bind -r "\C-l"
```

To disable permanently for Bash, put the above command in your `~/.bashrc`. To disable permanently for any tool that uses readline, put the below line in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-l":
```

More information: `help bind`, `man bash`, `man 3 readline`.

---

#### Zsh

Zsh does not use readline. In your Zsh `bindkey | grep '\^L'` probably prints:

```
"^L" clear-screen
```

(possibly among other lines). To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, you need to remove this binding. In Zsh the command is:

```
bindkey -r "^L"
```

To disable permanently for Zsh, put the above command in your `~/.zshrc`.

More information: `man zshzle`.

Comment: Readers note that it's a capital `C`, though the glyph is rather short in this font.